# Java Очистка памяти с помощью null

Tags: java

Например у меня есть такие объекты:

```
AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
ParseContext pc = new ParseContext(); 
CustomBodyContentHandler ch = new CustomBodyContentHandler(-1);
```

Чтобы выделить под них память я пишу оператор new справа он знака равно, при этом такие объекты создаются в потоке, поэтому если много потоков, то и много таких объектов.

Когда поток заканчивает свою работу нужно очистить выделенную память, и хочется понять, нужно ли писать такое:

```
mimeType = null;
parser = null;
pc = null;
ch = null;
```

Или GC сам все удалит, потому что нет ссылки на эти объекты.

---

Подскажите как быть? Нужно ли писать null, чтобы очистить память и очищается ли она при этом?! Заранее спасибо за понимание.

Comment: Garbage Collector (GC) автоматически очищает неиспользуемые переменные, когда те выходят из зоны видимости, поэтому в большинстве случаев (почти всегда) писать null не нужно. Однако, есть тонкости, на эту тему написано большое количество статей в интернете, я думаю, вы сможете их найти самостоятельно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если поток завершился, значит стековая память (в которой хранятся ссылки на объекты, которые хранятся в куче) теперь пустая, а значит нет ссылок на эти объекты. Теперь остаётся ждать, когда `gc` проведёт следующую чистку, но на это мы уже повлиять не можем.

Самим присваивать `null` не требуется.